# PyUnit test hangs if use unittest.TextTestRunner and connect to remote server

Tags: python, paramiko, python-unittest

I'm trying to run tests via unittest.TextTestRunner. But i've faced with a problem: test execution hangs without any progress If test contains code that connects to remote server via ssh using paramiko. For some reason it hangs during connecting to remote server at this line:

> client.connect(hostname=host)

```
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
print("Before connect")
client.connect(hostname=host)
print("Connected to %s" % host)
```

Example of Test:

```
class Test(unittest.TestCase):
  def test_fail(self):
      connect_to_remote_server()
      self.assertEqual(1, 2, "1==2 Should fail")

suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(Test)
testResult = unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

Everything works fine if don't use unittest.TextTestRunner or don't connect to remote server.

Answer (score 0):

Seems, that this problem relates to https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/104

Workaround is:
add code

```
from paramiko import py3compat
py3compat.u("dirty hack")
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
default_backend()
```

before

> client.connect(hostname=host)